# What really happens when setText() is called on an EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, android-editable

This is a part of the code:

```
editText.setText("Some Text", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

Editable editable = (Editable) editText.getText();

// value of editable.toString() here is "Some Text"

editText.setText("Another Text", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

// value of editable.toString() is still "Some Text"
```

Why the value of editable.toString() did not change? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assigned `editText.getText()` to a variable. That means its value won't change.

When you call `setText()`, the original text is overwritten with the new CharSequence; the original instance of the Editable that `getText()` returns is no longer part of the TextView, so your `editable` variable is no longer attached to the TextView.

Take a look at TextView's `getEditableText()` (this is what EditText calls from `getText()`):

```
public Editable getEditableText() {
    return (mText instanceof Editable) ? (Editable) mText : null;
}
```

If `mText` is an Editable Object, then it'll return it. Otherwise, it'll return `null`.

`setText()` eventually makes its way to `setTextInternal()`:

```
private void setTextInternal(@Nullable CharSequence text) {
    mText = text;
    mSpannable = (text instanceof Spannable) ? (Spannable) text : null;
    mPrecomputed = (text instanceof PrecomputedText) ? (PrecomputedText) text : null;
}
```

As you can see, it just overwrites the `mText` field, meaning your Editable instance is no longer the instance that the EditText has.

[TextView.java](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java)

Comment: I agree with most of this answer, but simply assigning a value to a variable doesn't mean that the value will never change. `SpannableStringBuilder` implements `Editable`, and so the results of its `toString()` method can change over time.

Comment: @BenP. yes, but OP isn't using a SpannableStringBuilder. OP is using an EditText, which _does_ overwrite the variable returned by `getText()`. That means that the `editable` variable OP has won't change when `setText()` is called.

Comment: My point is just that the blanket statement "You assigned X to a variable, therefore X's value won't change" is not true in general. It may be true in this case, but it would be a bad lesson to "learn" for java programming in general.

Comment: It wasn't meant as a blanket statement.

Comment: ` Editable t = mEditableFactory.newEditable(text);
            text = t; ` also helped me a lot. Thanks